# How to create a function to convert monthly data to daily, weekly in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have the below monthly data in the dataframe and I need to convert the data to weekly, daily, biweekly.

```
date              chair_price     vol_chair
01-09-2018         23              30
01-10-2018         53              20

daily: price as same and vol_chair divided by days of the month
weekly: price as same and vol_chair divided by number of weeks in a month
```

expected output:
daily:

```
   date              chair_price     vol_chair
01-09-2018            23               1
02-09-2018            23               1
03-09-2018            23               1
..
30-09-2018            23               1
01-10-2018            53               0.64
..
31-10-2018            53               0.64
```

weekly:

```
     date              chair_price     vol_chair
02-09-2018               23              6
09-09-2018               23              6 
16-09-2018               23              6   
23-09-2018               23              6 
30-09-2018               23              6
07-10-2018               53              5
14-10-2018               53              5
..
```

I am using below code as for column vol, any quick way to do it together i.e. keep price same and vol - take action and find number of weeks in a month

```
df.resample('W').ffill().agg(lambda x: x/4)
df.resample('D').ffill().agg(lambda x: x/30)
and need to use calendar.monthrange(2012,1)[1] to identify days 
def func_count_number_of_weeks(df):
    return len(calendar.monthcalendar(df['DateRange'].year, df['DateRange'].month))

def func_convert_from_monthly(df, col, category, columns):
    if category == "Daily":
        df['number_of_days'] = df['DateRange'].dt.daysinmonth
        for column in columns:
            df[column] = df[column] / df['number_of_days'] 
        df.drop('number_of_days', axis=1, inplace=True)
    elif category == "Weekly":
        df['number_of_weeks'] = df.apply(func_count_number_of_weeks, axis=1)
        for column in columns:
            df[column] = df[column] / df['number_of_weeks'] 
        df.drop('number_of_weeks', axis=1, inplace=True)

    return df

def func_resample_from_monthly(df,col, category):
    df.set_index(col, inplace=True)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
    if category == "Monthly":
        df = df.resample('MS').ffill()
    elif category == "Weekly":
        df = df.resample('W').ffill()

    return df
```

Comment: Can you at least try something to show you're interested in solving your problem? You ask another one as soon as your previous one is solved. Stack Overflow is not free labour. You are expected to show your efforts.

Comment: sorry my bad, in a hurry mentioned it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimeindex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)

#add new next month for correct resample
idx = df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

df = df.append(df.iloc[[-1]].rename({df.index[-1]: idx}))

#resample with forward filling values, remove last helper row
#df1 = df.resample('D').ffill().iloc[:-1]
df1 = df.resample('W').ffill().iloc[:-1]

#divide by size of months
df1['vol_chair'] /= df1.resample('MS')['vol_chair'].transform('size')
print (df1)

            chair_price  vol_chair
date                              
2018-09-02           23        6.0
2018-09-09           23        6.0
2018-09-16           23        6.0
2018-09-23           23        6.0
2018-09-30           23        6.0
2018-10-07           53        5.0
2018-10-14           53        5.0
2018-10-21           53        5.0
2018-10-28           53        5.0
```

Comment: hi jezrael, thankss for the reply! I have also written similar code if you could review.
Also, why do we need to do iloc using df.resample('W').ffill().iloc[:-1]?

Comment: @user3222101 - because last row is `November`, it is only necessary for filled all October days. Be free omit it and check last rows in outputs.

Comment: This is very similar to what am trying to solve. Lets say a week overlaps between 2 months, how will this code handle it? will it divide between them based on number of days from each month?

Comment: @vevekseetharaman - Not easy say without data, best is create new question with sample data, expected output and what you try (be free add this solution there)

Comment: Sure @jezrael, will create a new question.